# jQuery AJAX contact form with PHP mailer jumping to mail page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a simple contact form, I have an old school php mailer mail.php and a jQuery front page from where I'm calling it.

As I wanted it to work, it should've stayed on same page, but it actually jumps to mail.php and displays the message
`Thank you for contacting me. I'll try to reach you ASAP.`
Though it does send the mail, thats still not acceptable as that was not my intention. Can anybody find out what I'm doing wrong here ?

Any help appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php   
$name = trim($_POST['name']);

$email = trim($_POST['email']);

if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
    $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
} else {
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);
}

$emailTo = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission from '.$name;
$sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";
$headers = 'From: Saddi website <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo "Thank you for contacting me. I'll try to reach you ASAP.";
return true;
?>
```

FORM (Lot of bootstrap tags there, so to keep it clean I'm just posting ):

```
    <form class="form" action="mail.php" method="post" id="contact-form">


                    </form>
```

And here goes my AJAX:

```
    var data_string = jQuery('#contact-form').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: {name:name,email:email,message:message}, 
        timeout: 6000,
        error: function(request,error) {
            if (error == "timeout") {
                jQuery('#timedout').fadeIn('slow');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#timedout').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 3000);
            }
            else {
                jQuery('#state').fadeIn('slow');
                jQuery("#state").html('The following error occured: ' + error + '');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#state').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 3000);
            }
        },
        success: function() {
            jQuery('span.valid').remove();
            jQuery('#thanks').fadeIn('slow');
            jQuery('input').val('');
            jQuery('textarea').val('');
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('#thanks').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 3000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i will recommend you to use jQuery Form Plugin, very helpful for this kind of ajax post and validations.

[jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Second, you can use event.preventDefault(); to avoid the default action of the link but it will really depend on how are you triggering your form to the ajax code

[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Danny, Apparently my AJAX code was not being called. So I'm re-working it, will try this in case my new one doesn't work too. Its an easy thing to do. Though I wish I wasn't on verge of passing out.

Comment: You are welcome @calZone if it works for you please feel free to accept the answer, if not tell me and i'll set a jsfiddle for you. Also try to check on the browser console for javascript errors to see if you can get a hint there.